# Поиск и замена подстрок "[N]" и "(N)" в строке

Tags: java

В строке "qwerty [5] uiopp (6) asdf (1) hjkl; [3]"
нужно найти и заменить все "[N]" на "RN", а "(N)" на "XN", где N- любая цифра.
Через regex я что-то не осилил, из-за скобок. 
Нужно что-то типа [/d] искать, но скобки для него означают совсем другое.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скобки как и прочие спец. знаки надо экранировать знаком экрана `\`.
И не забывайте, что `\` экран не только в regexp, но и в строках java.
Поэтому в java для изображения одного `\` надо писать два `\\`.

```
String s = "qwerty [5] uiopp (6) asdf (1) hjkl; [3]"
                 .replaceAll("\\[(\\d)\\]", "R$1")   // \[(\d)\]
                 .replaceAll("\\((\\d)\\)", "X$1");  // \((\d)\)
```

Круглые скобки без экрана отмечают группу символов, которую можно использовать  в строке замены. Вместо $n подставляется группа номер n.